Undocumented Prescribe commands?
I have several Kyocera Prescribe print jobs from a production environment (printing for several years). Some of these files contain commands+parameters which are not documented. (Rather the used parameters are missing or not documented).
Right now I found 3 of them: FPAT, SIMG and GRRD.
FPAT ;

generate fill pattern should have 8 values, but this command is parameterless. What should it do? all white pattern? all black pattern? reset the fill ?
SIMG 0;

set image model should have a value from 1 till 6 but value 0 is used. What should it do?
Both commands often occur side by side, for example:
!R! MAP 15,3.6; PAT 0,300; BLK 3,1,V; SIMG 0; FPAT ; EXIT;
GRRD J,1,1, <image>;ENDG;
here the <image> parameter is not a file name but the real image data embedded. Doesn't seem to be documented.
I guess that there are plenty of more undocumented commands/parameters.
(I'm using the "Prescribe Commands Command Reference" couldn't find any older references.)
